# How do I create a code in R that runs based on two-level condition?

Tags: r

In R I would like to produce two different elements, e.g. a and b

1. until one of these occurs x times (this would be a win for that element)
2. then based on the result in the first step repeat the procedure until one of the elements has y such wins

For instance, using x=3

```
result=integer(0)
while(TRUE){
result = c(result, sample(c("a","b"), 1))
if(
length(grep("a",result,value=T))>=3|length(grep("b",result,value=T))>=3)  
break
}
table(result)
```

would lead to

**result

a b

3 2**

and the win for a. I would like to repeat the procedure so it stops when a or b reaches say three such wins.

Grateful for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the simulation procedure you need?

```
simu_proc <- function(agents, x, y) {
  wins <- character(0L)
  repeat {
    res <- character(0L)
    repeat {
      res <- c(res, sample(agents, 1L))
      test_x <- table(res)
      won <- test_x >= x
      if (any(won)) {
        wins <- c(wins, names(test_x)[won])
        break
      }
    }
    test_y <- table(wins)
    won <- test_y >= y
    if (any(won)) {
      return(names(test_y)[won])
    }
  }
}
```

Some trials as follows:

```
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "b"
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "b"
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "b"
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "b"
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "a"
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "b"
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "a"
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[1] "b"
```

I did some further investigations out of curiosity. If you are ok with recursions and/or some functional programming stuff, I think you can generalise this procedure to allow arbitrary numbers of agents (i.e. the elements you try to produce) and cutoffs (i.e. the conditions at different levels). See the code below:

```
play <- function(game, cutoff) {
  results <- character(0L)
  repeat {
    results <- c(results, game())
    scoreboard <- table(results)
    won <- scoreboard >= cutoff
    if (any(won)) {
      return(names(scoreboard)[won])
    }
  }
}

play_proc <- function(agents, cutoffs) {
  recur_play <- function(agents, cutoffs) {
    if (length(cutoffs) < 2L) {
      return(function() play(function() sample(agents, 1L), cutoffs))
    }
    function() play(recur_play(agents, cutoffs[-1L]), cutoffs[[1L]])
  }
  recur_play(agents, rev(cutoffs))()
}
```

Some trials:

```
> play_proc(c("a", "b", "c"), c(1, 2, 3, 4))
[1] "b"
> play_proc(c("a", "b", "c"), c(1, 2, 3, 4))
[1] "b"
> play_proc(c("a", "b"), c(3, 3))
[1] "a"
> play_proc(c("a", "b"), c(3, 3))
[1] "b"
```

Return the result for each step:

```
simu_proc <- function(agents, x, y) {
  wins <- character(0L)
  process <- list()
  repeat {
    res <- character(0L)
    repeat {
      res <- c(res, sample(agents, 1L))
      test_x <- table(res)
      won <- test_x >= x
      if (any(won)) {
        wins <- c(wins, names(test_x)[won])
        process <- c(process, list(test_x))
        break
      }
    }
    test_y <- table(wins)
    won <- test_y >= y
    if (any(won)) {
      return(c(names(test_y)[won], process, list(test_y)))
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
> simu_proc(c("a", "b"), 3, 3)
[[1]]
[1] "b"

[[2]]
res
a b 
1 3 

[[3]]
res
b 
3 

[[4]]
res
a b 
1 3 

[[5]]
wins
b 
3
```

**Update**

```
simu_proc <- function(agents, x, y) {
  wins <- character(0L)
  process <- list()
  repeat {
    res <- character(0L)
    repeat {
      res <- c(res, sample(agents, 1L))
      test_x <- table(res)
      end <- any(test_x >= x) && (length(test_x) < 2L || abs(diff(test_x)) > 1L)
      if (end) {
        wins <- c(wins, names(test_x)[[which.max(test_x)]])
        process <- c(process, list(test_x))
        break
      }
    }
    test_y <- table(wins)
    end <- any(test_y >= y)
    if (end) {
      return(c(names(test_y)[[which.max(test_y)]], process, list(test_y)))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! That's exactly what I want. However, I would also like it to show all the part results on the way (my bad, I forgot to mention that).  However, I think I will be able to figure that part out, it should just be an additional component in return (as a list).

Comment: Hello again! It turns out that I spoke too soon. I have tried
return(list(names(test_y)[won],test_x,test_y))
but it returns only the last for test_x (for test_y it is just one anyway). I have never used repeat type of loop so I do not know how to capture the entire output, since there are no indices like in the for loop to capture it with [[i]] or [i] or similar. Again grateful for suggestions!

Comment: See the new post. @RavenR

Comment: Infinitely grateful for a quick answer. Now when I look at it seems very reasonable and logical to put it there and like that but still I don't think that I would thought of that in a million years.

Comment: Hello again! I was trying to add an additional condition to this. Namely this: if for instance the game is until three wins in the first step and the result is 2:2 then the game should continue until one of the players has two points advantage. I have tried to replace won <- test_x >= x  with won <- (test_x >= x & test_x[1] >= test_x[2] + 2) | (test_x >= x & test_x[2] >= test_x[1] + 2). Although it seemingly works it sometimes leads to a tied result 3:3 in the second step. In addition, if for instance the result is 3:2 not all 5 results from the first step are always presented. @ekoam

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got the logic right. The loop just needs to be rewritten. Here's my take :

```
cutoff=10
set.seed(1024)
result<- integer()
while(max(table(result)) <cutoff){
  
  result <-  c(result,  sample(c("a","b"), 1 ,prob = c(0.5,0.5)) )
  
}
table(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is much more elegant than mine. However, it still only takes care of the first part. ekoams' solution is more what I was looking for.